# Edit custom made number plate in GTA 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-ifruit

I created a custom plate using the iFruit app and I would like to change it to something else. How can I do that ? I try pressing on the number plate in the app but I cannot edit it anymore !

Comment: You can't change the plate more than once but if you REALLY need to you can always just create a new Social Club profile and then re-link all of your accounts to it. You will have to add all your friends and crews again but the linked accounts will bring all your game details with them. You can then set a new plate on this account.

Answer (score 1):

You can only change it when your plate expires on the month given on your plate

Answer (score 0):

You can only customize a plate once.  If you want something different you will have to get another plate.  I do not yet know how you unlock additional plates.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can only change it once even though it says you can change it if you get more plates.  How you get these, I do not know.